# C++ - Is it bad practice to have variables that are not class object properties inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, variables, definition

Suppose I have a class `Sensor` as shown below:

```
class Sensor
{
    public:
        Sensor();
        array <float, 3> marker_pos(float, float, float);

    private:
        float range;
        float phi;
        array <float, 3> temp;
        int flag = 0;
};
```

The variables `range` and `phi` are properties or variables of the sensor object. But the variables `temp` and `flag` are just normal variables that are to be used inside the function `marker_pose`.

**1.** Is it bad practice to define/declare `temp` and `flag` inside the class ?

**2.** If I define/declare them inside the function `marker_pose`, it will be defined every time I call that function. Is that a good idea?

**3.** What will be the best practice to follow in such situations ?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. See 1 and 2.

Comment: Note that your code and the alternative (2) are not interchangeable: With (2), multiple, concurrent calls of `marker_pos` all behave independently; with the given code, they race. Moreover, your given `marker_pos` is not reentrant. So I'd say the question isn't actually well posed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always define variables at the minimum possible scope. So if variables are only used inside a function, they should be defined in the function, not in the class.

Comment: So, after the function is executed, these variables will be destroyed and there will be no memory leak, right?

Comment: Yes. For all the types your class uses, there is no possibility of a memory leak for those types.

Comment: For lazy evaluation it can be valid to declare/define variables in the class even if they are only used inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you have to declare variables as late as you can (ie: **as deep in scope as you can**).

Minimize the `life span` of different variables may **enhance the visibility** of your code and **ease the debug and maintenance** of your program.